# Gassetic looking for file with _0 added to file name

Tags: gulp, assetic

In my gassetic.yml file I have the following

```
files:
    app.css: # This is the output filename
        - src/someBundle/app.scss
```

However when gassetic runs, I get an error saying src/someBundle/app_0.scss is missing.

If I create this file and edit it, its this app_0.scss that is compiled.

Why does gassetic / gulp look for this file when its not specified in my yml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It adds index of the file in the folder to avoid overwritting.

I think this is a bug but you can fix it by adding `autoRenaming: false` to the dev environment. See [Multiple Environments setup](https://github.com/crossborne/gassetic/blob/master/Resources/doc/MultipleEnvironments.md)